# Spring Security Login return 404

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

i've searched tons of google pages but i still can't find solution for this. I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate and Security. I've followed [this](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hibernate-annotation-example/) tutorial but when i submit login form it goes for 404.

**NOTE**
login url is : **localhost:8080/Portfolio/login** after submit it is: **localhost:8080/login**

**CONFIG**

```
package com.portfolio.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.portfolio")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver setupViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource()
    {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
    {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pl"));
        resolver.setCookieName("locale");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(86400);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
    {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("locale");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

**HIBERNATE CONFIG**

```
package com.portfolio.config;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.portfolio.config" })
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class Hibernate {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.portfolio.entity");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);

        return txManager;
    }
}
```

**SECURITY CONFIG**

```
package com.portfolio.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customerUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
}
```

**SECURITY WEB APP INITIALIZER**

```
package com.portfolio.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

**SPRING MVC INITIALIZER**

```
package com.portfolio.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { Config.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.portfolio.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("login");

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage()
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("user", getPrincipal());
        mv.setViewName("admin");

        return mv;
    }

    private String getPrincipal()
    {
        String username = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }

        return username;
    }
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body class="security-app">
<div class="details">
    <h2>Spring Security - JDBC Authentication</h2>
    <a href="http://www.programming-free.com/2015/09/spring-security-jdbc-authentication.html" class="button green small">Tutorial</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/priyadb/SpringSecurityJdbcApp/archive/master.zip"
       class="button red small">Download</a>
</div>

<form action="/login" method="post">

    <div class="lc-block">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="style-4" name="ssoId" id="username"
                   placeholder="User Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" class="style-4" name="password" id="password"
                   placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="button red small" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.portfolio</groupId>
  <artifactId>Portfolio</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Portfolio Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.9.3</joda-time.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Joda-Time -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
      <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Portfolio</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments - you are currently posting to an incorrect URL.

In the linked tutorial you see in the view they have the code:

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

But you are posting directly to "/login" - I assume from your other info that "Portfolio" is the application context, so by posting directly to /login tries to find another context on your app server called "login".

The JSP tag c:url is probably working out the application specific URL based on your context (so you don't have to hardcode the name of your app into the view).

In the very least, switching to that approach as per the tutorial you will no longer get this experience:

> NOTE login url is : localhost:8080/Portfolio/login after submit it is:
>   localhost:8080/login

as it will start posting to your application.  Once you have that change, and are posting to your app URL, you may still get other errors, but you should at least start getting Spring logging (as the request will make it to the Spring app now) - so if it still fails after that, then add the logs/error you get in that case.

Comment: it works ! i also added this `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` to login.jsp and `.and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")` to Security config. Now when i log in as user with admin role, it goes to `/admin` but gives `access denied`

Comment: Cool - how are you setting the roles in the UserDetailsService? (the example in the tutorial explicitly adds "ROLE_" at the start of the role, but their security config just does hasRole("ADMIN") - I can't remember the details exactly, but have been caught out by this stuff before - somewhere the ROLE_ prefix is defaulted - so if your UserDetailsService is exactly the same as the tutorial, try changing you security config to just check for the role without the ROLE_ prefix

Comment: My UserDetialsService is the same as the tutorial. I removed the ROLE_ prefix but it still gives Access Denied msg

Comment: It works ! I forgot to add the csrf hidden input. Thank you guys, you're awesome !